# Development environment requirements for Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

Can someone help me out in understanding the System Requirements and dependencies required for setting up a development environment for Bitcoin Core?

What else is required apart from the Bitcoin Core source?

Comment: What did you try? What errors did you encounter?

Comment: Please explain what you actually need.  Is there something missing from the [development documentation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/doc)?  Best to try it first, then post **specific** questions or problems here if you really cannot find the answer via google / or search on this site.

Answer (score 1):

All the info you should need is here:

- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/doc